# Using \color in \Block causes the contents to drop below the baseline

Tags: nicematrix

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{hvlines}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{r l X[l, t]}
        
        Basmah
        & Fadeel
        & \Block[l, t]{1-1}{\color{IndianRed1}
            text}
        \\
        
    \end{NiceTabularX}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: use \leavevmode before the color command.

Comment: footnote page 7 `texdoc grfguide`: "not my fault"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. May you elaborate on this in an answer? It is also possible to modify the answer of Simon Dispa

Answer (score 1):

`nicematrix` uses tikz nodes. Inside a node you can use `\textcolor{<color>}{<text>}`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{hvlines}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{r l X[l, t]}
        
        Basmah
        & Fadeel
        & \Block[l, t]{1-1}{\textcolor{IndianRed1}{text}} % changed <<<<<<<<<<
        \\
        
    \end{NiceTabularX}
    
\end{document}
```